# Is there a way to run a JAR online WITHOUT Java Web Start?

Tags: java, html, jar, jframe

I believe about half a year ago I read somewhere it is possible, but (now I'm kicking myself) I didn't save the page I got it from. I was in a hurry, and maybe I misunderstood, but is there a way to run a JAR file without it being a JApplet? Specifically, is it possible to use an HTML5 tag to run a JAR file which uses JFrames? Thank you for any help you guys may provide